# How to use Snackbar without support library?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library, android-snackbar

I am developing an Android app which doesn't require backward compatibility. Target SDK version is 22 as of now. I am using native Activity and Fragment and application theme is android:Theme.Material.Light.
My problem is that I'm not able to use Snackbar with the existing setup, it throws exceptions like

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.Snackbar$SnackbarLayout E/AndroidRuntime(19107): at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:640) E/AndroidRuntime(19107): at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:750)

I googled but couldn't find any example of snackbar with Activity. So is it necessary to use support library like

> AppCompatActivity or android.support.v4.app.Fragment.

in order to use Snackbar in my app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the support design library `compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'` for it to work:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
}
```

([Read more in detail here](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-snackbar-example/))

Comment: But again it would ask me to change the theme and then AppCompatActivity and more. That's my question is. With your change I'm again getting exception "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library."

Comment: SnackBar is contained in that library so you'll need to add a dependency if you want to use the feature. And satisfy the library with all required constraints. Otherwise you can try an external library which just mimics the behavior of Snackbar. But, that would come with its own limitations and will not give an experience like the original SnackBar.

Comment: Which means in order to use Snackbar I will have to use support library(AppCompatActivity etc.), and 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1' is not compatible with standard Material themes.

Comment: yeah it works even with Activity and Fragment, just gradle and theme change required.

Comment: @Amit, what must I change in theme?

Comment: @AlexeySubbota check the themes start with Theme.AppCompat or see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41526839/snackbar-on-android-without-changing-theme

Answer (score 2):

Yes, add dependencies on your gradle

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
```

Then, change your app theme accordingly, you need to use the `AppCompat` theme. Create the following theme on your `Styles.xml`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

In your manifest then: add `@style/AppTheme` on application and add `@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar` on every activity

```
<application
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
     </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're stubborn like me and you don't want to use the support libs, but want to use the snackbar in your app, there is an option for you. I found [this deprecated library](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1160) that is essentially the Snackbar you know, just independent from the support libs. It works fine for me, however it might not have some features such as moving a FloatingActionButton upwards when appearing.

Comment: Brilliant tip. Very nice - saved me a third failed attempt to employ the 'AppCompat' can of worms.