# Snackbar on Android without changing theme

Tags: java, android, android-layout

When I create a snackbar on Android I get this error:
"java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity".

I don't want to change the theme to AppCompat of my activity, Is there a way I can have the snackbar without changing the theme?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either you are using `appcompat-v7` (`AppCompatActivity`, `Theme.AppCompat`, etc.), or you are not. You need to be consistent, so if you are not going to use `Theme.AppCompat`, make sure you are not extending `AppCompatActivity`.

However, the Design Support library — the source of [the official `Snackbar`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/Snackbar.html) — only supports activities using `appcompat-v7`. If you want a snackbar without `appcompat-v7`, you cannot use the Design Support library. Instead, use some other implementation of a snackbar.

I just released a [library](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-crossport) that offers a port of the official `Snackbar` that works without `appcompat-v7`, but it only works with projects that have `minSdkVersion` of 21 or higher. [This library](https://github.com/MrEngineer13/SnackBar) implements a snackbar that works on older devices, though the project is discontinued. There may be other implementations.

Comment: I see,

Can you suggest a custom implementation for in app notifications like snackbar? 
I just asked it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41531125/snackbar-lookalike-in-app-notifications-for-activities-not-using-appcompat-v7