# Snackbar lookalike (in app notifications) for activities not using appcompat-v7

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I want to show in app notifications (not a dialog, but a light weight in app notification), 
It should also have button similar to what hangouts does:
[image]

I cannot use snackbar given that activities in my app **do not use** appcompat-v7: [Snackbar on Android without changing theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41526839/snackbar-on-android-without-changing-theme/41526899#41526899),
Is there a way to implement the above feature **without** using external libraries like TSnackbar, etc. 
Is fragment a good idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would change your activities to use AppCompat.  Its probably the least amount of work.  If you're unwilling to do that, yes you can make a Fragment that does the same thing. A basic Snackbar isn't that difficult.

Answer (score 0):

You can use toast.

```
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    CharSequence text = "Hello toast!";
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
    toast.show();
```